# What is a stub from the lightning grpc documentation?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, grpc

For example, very often in the [lightning documentation](https://api.lightning.community) for their grpc api, you will see the following boilerplate python code:

```
>>> import codecs, grpc, os
>>> import rpc_pb2 as ln, rpc_pb2_grpc as lnrpc
>>> macaroon = codecs.encode(open('LND_DIR/data/chain/bitcoin/simnet/admin.macaroon', 'rb').read(), 'hex')
>>> os.environ['GRPC_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES'] = 'HIGH+ECDSA'
>>> cert = open('LND_DIR/tls.cert', 'rb').read()
>>> ssl_creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(cert)
>>> channel = grpc.secure_channel('localhost:10009', ssl_creds)
>>> stub = lnrpc.LightningStub(channel)
```

I am curious, what is an LightningStub? Looking a bit deeper into rpc_pb2_grpc, which seems to be a generated file you'll find the following ( lacking ) bit of documentation:

```
class LightningStub(object):
  # missing associated documentation comment in .proto file
  pass
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, it is grpc nomenclature. According to the [documentation at grpc.io](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#using-the-api-surface):

> gRPC users typically call these APIs on the client side and implement
>   the corresponding API on the server side.
>
> ...
>
> On the client side, the client has a local object known as stub (for
>   some languages, the preferred term is client) that implements the same
>   methods as the service.

Which pretty much means using grpc on the client side looks like you're interacting with an object that performs the operations locally - when in reality that object ( known as a **stub** ) is making calls to the server asking it to perform certain actions.